# Qt: Add margins to the visibleRegion of a Map

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt5.12

I have a `Map` that fills the window and some locations from which I generate a `georectangle`. I want to set the `visibleRegion` of the `Map` to the `georectangle` but I also want a margin (in pixels) a the bottom of the window for overlays, so that the locations are never hidden behind the overlays. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.